# Mathematically, what delimits “information theory”?

Tags: philosophy-of-computer-science, information-theory

I can expand on what I mean in a little bit, but it seems to me that as you go deep into various foundational aspects of math (or more generally, pattern, structure, reason, information, meaning), you arrive at very fundamental theories which can be hard to separate from one another (set theory, logic, etc.)

To me, what I understand to be information theory has always seemed immediately inseparable from things like set theory and logic.

I can add more detail to this answer shortly, but I am curious: down at the “bottom”, is there any clear-cut, non-arbitrary way to separate information theory from other fundamental theories like logic? It seems as though if you try to define basic structural or semantically substantial systems in terms of primitive notions, you are basically creating deductive systems which generate “information”. Is there any obvious mathematical characteristic which separates what “information theory” is merely from logic in general?

Comment: What separates geometry from set theory and logic? What separates topology from set theory and logic? What separates number theory from set theory and logic? Etc

Comment: I'm not sure about "delimits",  but no classical branch of mathematics introduces (or discusses) stuff like Kolmogorov complexity, e.g., https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity , at least I don't think so. Of course, conversely, classical math is extensively used to study and discuss Kolmogorov complexity, etc. But the idea to discuss it in the first place arises from, broadly construed,  "information theory".

Answer (score 1):

Sic, Caesar! Salve?

**What makes information theory fundamentally different and mathematical is that under Nyquist, Shannon, and others, the tools of mathematical analysis were devised to the evaluate properties of messages, both at the symbolic level, and at the level of the communication medium.** No other mathematical theory attempts to do this. Communication has been studied a long time by linguists and communication theorists, an example of which is [Roman Jakobson and his model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Jakobson#The_communication_functions). But after the advent of the telegraph, in which communication began to be understood more in terms of physics and mathematics of signaling, the **tools of mathematics were turned on the process with more vigor and an eye on abstracting away from the message itself to the technology** that implemented delivery of the message.

**One important impetus was [signals intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_intelligence)**. Codes and ciphers go back to at least the Roman empire, but with the new-found media of mechanical systems and electrical signals, having a mathematical understanding of information in an abstract sense took on a new priority. Consider Turing's work at [Bletchley Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bletchley_Park). Cracking the Engima was an effort that drove Turing to propose a definition of computation, which is at the heart of information processing. **But to process information, one has to describe it.** Codes, for instance can be understood in terms of frequency, probability, permutations, computational difficulty, and so on. **At the heart of all of these efforts is having an adequate definition and description of information itself.**

**Of course, today it is obvious that we should use binary mathematics and other mathematical theories to describe information.** That's what makes information theory an applied mathematics. It models computation and communication in the real world. Digital signal processing is a core feature of electronics and computer engineering. A cryptanalyst can use frequency tables for the appearance of strings of bits that encode symbols in a language. We can talk about channel capacity and throughput in terms of such quantification. Thus information theory and [physical theories of computation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/) are strongly interrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make it clear to me, what your point is and your precise question. Hence I cannot attempt any specific answer.

I think it could be a good idea to refer to the following book which covers the whole subject. I quote from the introduction of
Yves Nievergelt: [Logic, Mathematics, and Computer Science. Modern Foundations with Practical Applications](https://www.amazon.de/Logic-Mathematics-Computer-Science-Applications/dp/1493937138):

> This text discusses the foundations where logic, mathematics, and
> computer science begin. The intended readership consists of
> undergraduate students majoring in mathematics or computer science who
> must learn such foundations either for their own interest or for
> further studies. For a motivated reader, there are no technical
> prerequisites: you need not know any technical subject to start
> reading this text.